# Rpm change release number with setup.py

Tags: python, rpm, setup.py

The following is my `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

packages=find_packages("src")

setup(name='myapp',
        version='0.2.0',
        url='http://loom.st',
        author='Loom',
        author_email='admin@loom.st',
        package_dir={'': 'src'},
        packages=packages,
        )
```

I built rpm with command `python setup.py bdist_rpm` and have got files:

```
myapp-0.2.0-1.noarch.rpm
myapp-0.2.0-1.src.rpm
myapp-0.2.0.tar.gz
```

Why I have `1` in rpm file names and how I can manage what to show on this place?

Answer (score 1):

The `1` is called the **release number**. As you can see in the [documentation:](https://docs.python.org/2.0/dist/creating-rpms.html), when you call setup.py, you can pass him the option `--release` to define the release number like this:

```
python setup.py bdist_rpm --release=0
```

Answer (score 0):

This number is called **release** number. For the same version (0.2.0 in your case) you can have various releases. E.g. because ABI of some dependency changed and you need to rebuild it agains updated dependency. Or you added some security patch. Part of the release number is usually **dist** tag. E.g.: myapp-0.2.0-1.el6.noarch.rpm, myapp-0.2.0-1.el5.noarch.rpm. So the ".el5" and ".el6" are in fact part of release number. And it helps you better describe what release it is actualy. Because %{python_sitelib} is on el5 is different from path on el6 so the binary RPMs are different.

Release number usualy start with 1.

You can find more information at https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:NamingGuidelines#Release_Tag

BTW, you will get better result if you use pyp2rpm for generating rpm packges.